# python logging module no output while running in crontab

Tags: python, linux, shell, cron, centos6

I hava executable a.py file worked fine when running in CLI. But after I wrote a a.sh script `/root/a.py >> /root/a.log` and start a crontab `* * * * * /bin/sh /root/a.sh`, it worked fine except no outputting  in the log file.
The logging part of a.py was configured as follows:

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
LOG_FILE = 'log'
RESULT_LOG_FILE = 'result.log'
LOG_FORMAT = '[%(asctime)s] [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] [%(levelname)s] [%(threadName)s] [%(process)d] %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=LOG_FORMAT, datefmt=DATE_FORMAT, level=logging.INFO, filename=LOG_FILE)  
logging.error('ERROR')
```

I have tried to add  `/usr/local/bin/python` in front of `/root/a.py` in a.sh but it did not work. I have no idea why this happened.

Comment: what log file did you check? the result.log or the a.log? according to your code the log file will be result.log and a.log should be empty.

Comment: Both of them no log outputting. In the code listed above it should be 'log' file, I configured in `logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE)`

Comment: I mean both of 'log' and 'result.log' no output, there are some `print` statement output in a.log

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `/root/a.py >> /root/a.log` does **output redirection** into the file `/root/a.log`. The `>>` = append, whereas `>` would overwrite.

Your script is logging to `result.log`, not `a.log`. And unless you have a `print` statement, nothing is going to go into `a.log`.

In your `logging.basicConfig`, log events are not output to console, only to the log file, so there is no "output" to re-direct to `a.log`.

(Add a `print 'hello console'` in your script, you should see that in `a.log`.)

Edit from comments:

`result.log` may not be where you think. Since its path is determined by where it's executed from, not where the script is. Change `RESULT_LOG_FILE = 'result.log'` to `RESULT_LOG_FILE = '/root/result.log'`

Comment: Actually I have `print` statement in a.py file and it shown in a.log. But the output of `logging.error('ERROR')` did not record in the log(LOG_FILE) as what I configured in `logging.basicConfig`.

Comment: `result.log` may not be where you think. Since its path is determined by where it's executed from, not where the script is. Change `RESULT_LOG_FILE = 'result.log'` to `RESULT_LOG_FILE = '/root/result.log'` and try.